# How to create a price chart in Google Charts API?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-api, google-visualization

Look at the first chart on this page: http://viewcoin.com/charts

Basically, the first chart should show a line chart of historical price:

```
<div width="960" height="320" 
    data-chart-type="LineChart" 
    data-datasets='{"Price":{"15659":["2012-11-15T00:00:00.000Z",0.05],"15685":["2012-12-11T00:00:00.000Z",0.05],"15686":["2012-12-12T00:00:00.000Z",0.05],"15714":["2013-01-09T00:00:00.000Z",0.05],"15718":["2013-01-13T00:00:00.000Z",0.3],"15722":["2013-01-17T00:00:00.000Z",0.3],"15735":["2013-01-30T00:00:00.000Z",0.37],"15797":["2013-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",0.3],"15893":["2013-07-07T00:00:00.000Z",0.3],"15895":["2013-07-09T00:00:00.000Z",0.3],"15900":["2013-07-14T00:00:00.000Z",0.2],"15987":["2013-10-09T00:00:00.000Z",0.2],"16017":["2013-11-08T00:00:00.000Z",0.1],"16077":["2014-01-07T00:00:00.000Z",0.11],"16081":["2014-01-11T00:00:00.000Z",0.1],"16082":["2014-01-12T00:00:00.000Z",0.11],"16163":["2014-04-03T00:00:00.000Z",0.1],"16174":["2014-04-14T00:00:00.000Z",0.1],"16339":["2014-09-26T00:00:00.000Z",0.1],"16721":["2015-10-13T00:00:00.000Z",0.1],"16763":["2015-11-24T00:00:00.000Z",0.1]}}' 
    data-use-previous-row='1' 
    class="chart">
```

The problem is that the data is not showing up on the chart because of it's date pre-dates the current date. So, what happens is that there is no points in the dataset that appear in the chart, and as a side effect, the price points will all be at 0 rather than the previous point (the whole chart is flat).

My question is: how can I make a Google Chart that properly shows the price (using the latest price as the current price for today and every day since the price change)?

Comment: not following --> _date pre-dates the current date_ -- the chart can display any date, regardless of relation to _current date_...??

Comment: If that's the case, why isn't the chart displaying those dates?